# Convert Factor variable to date

Tags: r, date

I have a vector which has date embedded in it but has data type `Factor`.

Example

```
time  
[1] Jan-14 Feb-14 Mar-14 Apr-14  
Levels: Apr-14 Feb-14 Jan-14 Mar-14
```

I would like to separate year and month from this using R. Other similar questions had the correct format of date i.e Y-M-D, so on..
Can anyone suggest any idea?

I tried using `strsplit()`. It seperates the date like this

```
time<-strsplit(x = as.character(time), split = "-")  
time  
[[1]]  
[1] "Jan" "14"   
[[2]]  
[1] "Feb" "14"   
[[3]]  
[1] "Mar" "14"  
[[4]]  
[1] "Apr" "14"
```

How do I save these month and year in new column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can paste with a day number and use `as.Date`

```
as.Date(paste0(time,"-01"), "%b-%y-%d")
#[1] "2014-01-01" "2014-02-01" "2014-03-01" "2014-04-01"
```

If we need to separate to two columns

```
read.table(text=as.character(time), sep="-", col.names = c("Month", "Year"))
#   Month Year
#1   Jan   14
#2   Feb   14
#3   Mar   14
#4   Apr   14
```

#### data

```
time <- factor(c("Jan-14", "Feb-14", "Mar-14", "Apr-14"))
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response! But this will work if data is small. If I have to do same for Jan-14 to Dec-16, how should I proceed?